# I want to display an option list for configurable attributes on product list page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, php

I want to display an option list for configurable attributes on product list page in magento, just like it appears on product view page for configurable products.I tried everything but nothing is working, looked for some similar topics but they are useless.Please help me resolve this issue.

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $sidebar=Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_listing/sidebar');
    $i=0;
    $count=0;
    $span=3;
    $p_in_row=4;
    $type=Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_listing/product_listing_image_size');
    if($type=='small')
    {
        $span=2;
        $p_in_row=6;
    }




?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="category-products aligncenter">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('buyshop_no_products')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php  echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php
        $widthBig=258;
        $heightBig=245;
        $widthSmall=71;
        $heightSmall=65;
        $count++;
        ?>

        <!--PRODUCT-->
        <div class="row product-listing">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getProductHtml($_product,$this,$widthBig,$heightBig,$span,false,true,true,false,$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true))?>
            <div class="span6 product-detailes">
                <h3 class="product-name bottom-line"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl()?>"><?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true)?></a></h3>
                <div class="bottom-line">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <div class="product-review">
                        <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getStars($_product)?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom-line"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?></div>
                <div class="product-buttons">
                    <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->addToCartLink($_product,$this,true)?>
                    <div class="add-to-links">
                        <ul>
                            <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->addWishCompLink($_product,$this,true)?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--PRODUCT EOF-->




        <?php  endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>


<?php if(!empty(Mage::registry('current_category')->name)):?>
    <h2><?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->name ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($sidebar):?><div class="row big_with_description"><?php endif; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php  if(!$_product->isSaleable() && !Mage::getStoreConfig('cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock'))continue; ?>
        <?php
        $widthBig=258;
        $heightBig=245;
        $widthSmall=71;
        $heightSmall=65;
        $count++;
        ?>

        <?php
            if(!$sidebar)
            {
                $i++;
                if($i==1)echo '<div class="row big_with_description">';
            }
            $price=$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
        ?>

        <!--PRODUCT-->
        <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getProductHtml($_product,$this,$widthBig,$heightBig,$span,false,true,false,true,$price)?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getProductHover($_product,$this,$widthBig,$heightBig,$widthSmall,$heightSmall,$type,true,true,$price)?>
        <!--PRODUCT EOF-->


        <?php
        if(!$sidebar)
        {
            if($i==$p_in_row || $count==count($_productCollection))
            {
                echo '</div>';
                $i=0;
            }
        }
        ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if($sidebar):?></div><?php endif; ?>


    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: In what sense is "nothing working"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I tried writing some code from product/view.html but since i am a beginner with magento, i don't know exactly which code to use form it.Also, i tried looking for some code on stack overflow from a similar question but still i can't see that option list.